# Is it possible to assign two different aliases for the same predicate in a JSON-LD context file?

Tags: rdf, json-ld

I am writing a context file (.json) for JSON-LD. I understand that the alias→predicate mapping is one to one, that is, each alias maps to exactly one predicate (obviously). But is it the other way around as well? Or can I define two different aliases to describe the same predicate?

This is just for making the JSON-LD more readable and intuitive.

This is what I am trying to do:

```json
    "headword": {
        "@id": "ontolex:lexicalForm"
    },
    "wordform": {
        "@id": "ontolex:lexicalForm"
    }
```

I think it should work but I'd like to hear from someone who's actually done this before.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. JSON-LD tools generally use the full IRIs when processing the data, so they'll probably get confused. I tried playing around with it in the [JSON-LD playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/) and while it doesn't give any error, it does not display the data correctly.

Comment: Yes you can do this. But why didn't you simply try it and see if it works? It seems it takes as much effort to connect to SO and ask the question than trying it out yourself.

Comment: “I tried it and it seemed to work” is the source of a thousand bugs. I don’t see what’s wrong with asking for confirmation on SO.

Comment: Well, for the reasons cygri described. I am using MongoDB to manage my database, and since I am trying to validate huge amounts of data, I’d rather be 100% sure that this could be done, rather than possibly have thousands of files failing a schema - since mongoDB does not tell you the reason for failing the schema, I need to know exactly which parts work. Like kidney said, I tried RDF playground but that does not give errors - but I’ve had other issues with it before with the context and so I’d rather not rely on that either. I don’t see a problem in making sure in SO ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld/#context-definitions) it really seems to be possible!?

Even if possible, **don't do it!**

1. It makes your context harder to read. The reader has to search for all occurrences of an IRI to get the whole picture.
2. It is counter intuitive. A context is a technical document, why introduce this sort of redundancy?
3. It makes conversion from Rdf to Json unpredictable, since it is not clear what Json-Key will be used!